# NestJS - Correct way of setting redis subscribers in a custom provider

Tags: redis, nestjs, node-redis

I'm building a simple application that will subscribe to a number of channels in a redis database.

Given the following code in the redis service:

```js
// redis.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
const NRP = require('node-redis-pubsub');

const config = {
  port: 6379,
};

@Injectable()
export class RedisService {
  private nrpClient = new NRP(config)
  constructor() {
    this.simpleListener()
  }

  simpleListener() {
    this.nrpClient.on('__keyspace@0__:mykey', (data) => {
      console.log(data)
    })
  }

}
```

and the code in the redis module:

```js
// redis.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { RedisService } from './redis.service';

@Module({
  providers: [RedisService]
})
export class RedisModule {}
```

I've achieved the expected behavior for my application.
If I enter a session in my `redis-cli` and run:

```sh
127.0.0.1:6379> SADD mykey "test"
```

Then the NestJS logger prints the following:

```
[Nest] 306987   - 05/04/2021, 9:01:41 PM   [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +5ms
sadd
```

My question here is concerning my implementation design, rather than it's functionality.
There's a great lack of examples and documentation regarding the subject so I followed my instincts and wrote the code above based on [this](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/1392#issuecomment-464366705) recommendation.

Then, given that a provided class will be a singleton if registered as a "provider" in the redis module, I simply did that and called the function that creates the subscription in the redis service constructor.

I'm just worried that I'm not following the best guidelines in building a custom NestJS provider, also I don't really know if setting up the listeners in the constructor is the best idea.

Is this the best/correct way of implementing the desired behavior?