# Nestjs Redis event-listener

Tags: node.js, redis, nestjs, event-listener

I have a project that is on Nestjs framework and I want to listen to a specific key on Redis in an @Injectable() provider and change some values in that class based on the change that happened on that specific key. Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: see if this helps u: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67393677

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful